# Should you do more than one exercise per set?

Tags: exercise-technique, muscle-gain, sets

I currently do squats, barbell curls,  sit ups and bench press all in one go- consecutively -THEN i take a break and repeat a few more times before moving on.

I was wondering if i was taking the wrong approach as when i've looked around at different strength and muscle building workouts i see stuff similar to the above, except i'd have a break in between each. I've seen that more frequently than my method, but wouldn't it make sense to take less breaks like i do overall, to increase hypertrophy, etc?

Answer (score 1):

From the research that I have read, the length of your break has no influence on hypertrophy. The best indicator of hypertrophy is either volume, as in tonnage (sets times reps times weight) increasing over time, or more recently the number of "hard" sets per workout, meaning the number of sets which leave you close to technical failure (not at failure or past failure, just close to it). Doing exercises one by one gives you more time to recover and go harder on the next sets (meaning you can do a greater volume on hard sets), which is thus more optimal for hypertrophy.

All that being said, what you are doing right now is called supersets/multisets and it can be ok to some extent to save time. For example, I frequently superset antagonistic movements (bench press with dumbbell rows, overhead press with chin-ups, etc.) because they don't really influence each other, but I always keep at least one of them light. I wouldn't recommend doing more than 3 exercises though, and no more than 1 heavy compound lift at a time (squat, bench, deadlift, overhead press, barbell rows...) to stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

This would be what some call a "giant" super set. Usually a super set is 2 moves, but I have done giant super sets up to 4 moves (usually 1 or 2 of the moves being body weight moves though). I use supersets almost exclusively when I workout. You can do antagonist muscles as mentioned before, but you can also do the same muscle group. For arms I always superset a bicep move with a tricep move. However, on shoulder day I will superset two shoulder moves, but usually try to focus on different parts of the shoulder. For example, dumbbell press with shrugs, or rear delt flys with a front dumbbell raise. It's really up to you! Just make sure if you are doing heavy weights throughout such a long super set that you have a spot as you may become fatigued much faster this way.